# How to protect 1 column from editing?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have big spread sheet with multiple tabs and i am sharing it with my coworkers.

In column D on each tab I have same set of formulas.
Unfortunately my collages keep deleting them so I'm desperate to find the way to block it from editing. G sheets protection doesn't work as it disables filter function which is much needed.

I'm trying to block 1 column from editing in every tab on the spreadsheet.

I tried to use this but I don't understand why it isn't working really

```
function onEdit() {} 
    if(entryRange.getColumn() == 2) {
        e.range.setValue((e.oldvalue == undefined? "": e.oldvalue))
    }
```

Comment: do you want them to be able to edit the spreadsheets at all? you can set to view only for each person?

Comment: Yes, they need to edit all other parts but column d. They also need ability to use filter and sort column d, that's why i cannot use build-in protection function.

Comment: I tried to use this but i don't understand why it isnt working really `function onEdit() {}

if(entryRange.getColumn() == 2)
{                              
        e.range.setValue((e.oldvalue == undefined? "": e.oldvalue))
        }
     
`

Comment: Is this about programming or on how to use google spreadsheets? if the former, please post your code. if it's the later, the question is off-topic here.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify. Do NOT add comments. Not all comments will be visible initially, you cannot format your code in comments, and comment order may or may not be preserved. Make it easy for people to help you. You should probably also read the help tour.

Comment: I fixed some typos in your question and spelled out 'ss' to spreadsheet. I'm not sure whether you mean Google by G or whether that refers to column G. You should probably edit your question amd clarify. I've moved your code from comment to question where it's easier to read. Please double check it and edit it, looks like I copied your syntax errors as well.

Comment: For starters, `entryRange` is undefined.  You can't call `e` unless it's a argument in your function first. Col D is Number  4. value ≠ formula.Research and  Rewrite your code